# Debug does not work in IntelliJ IDEA after node version has been changed by NVM

Tags: node.js, linux, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm

When I install node from nvm all been okay. But after switching node to another version the debugger stopped working. Now you need to click on the link in the log to run the debugger in a separate process (`ws://127.0.0.1:9229/128dbc4c-8362-4af4-a480-f5e3910a3fa1`), but that wrong way to use.

Nothing helps: switching to the old version, setting the default version with nvm alias, and exporting symlinks in the `.zshrc` file also did not help.

```
export NVM_SYMLINK_CURRENT=true
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I'm using Fedora 37 Linux. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: Console output while app started

```
[17:18:18] Starting compilation in watch mode...    
[17:18:21] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.    
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/fe863646-063e-48f4-96ea-bd985cb4cad9
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[Nest] 74159   - 10.05.2023, 17:18:22   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
```

**UPDATE2**: Idea log after start project in debug mode: [log file](https://pastebin.com/k3MkunQt)

Comment: please could you share the full console output after starting the debug session plus the idea.log?

Comment: @lena ofcourse, qst was updated

Comment: looks ok; please couldyou share the idea.log?

Comment: @lena ofcourse, link with logs was attached

Comment: by the way, I have the same problem on ubuntu

Comment: Nothing suspicious in th log. BTW, clicking the link is a [right way](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2023.1/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#ws_node_debug_from_run_tw) to create and start the **Attach to Node.js** run configuration to attacha debugger to app started with `--inspect` switch, what's wrong with this way of debugging? How did you debug your code before?

Comment: @lena Before I switch the version with nvm for the first time, everything works by clicking on the debug button. No need to look for links in the logs, and no need to start a new dev process when working in --watch mode. This is very inconvenient, and it is clear that specifically changing versions using nvm causes this bug. In other OS (windows), this bug is not reproduced.